# Saving Listview contents to ms access db

Tags: ms-access, listview, vb6

I have added another column header to my listview `VAT` that loads from another table and populates to the listview. So far that is working fine.  Now, am trying to save the information from the listview to another table which is proving to be difficult.

I've been searching on the web for a week now but in vain here is my code on loading to listview.

```
Public Sub cmdLookup_Click()
On Error GoTo SearchError

With Connect.rsitem
 .Filter = "Itemno = '" & txtSearch.Text & "' or desc1 like '" & txtSearch.Text & _
     "*' or desc2 like '" & txtSearch.Text & "*' or upc = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
  
     .Open
    If .RecordCount > 1 Then
       FrmSearch.Show vbModal
   End If
   If .RecordCount > 0 Then
      QtyRemain = !onhandqty
   If QtyRemain > 0 Then
         Set x = ListView.ListItems.Add(, , !itemno)
            x.SubItems(1) = !desc1
            x.SubItems(2) = !desc2
            x.SubItems(3) = !Size
            x.SubItems(4) = 1
            x.SubItems(5) = FormatNumber(!unitprice)
            x.SubItems(6) = FormatNumber(!unitprice)
            x.SubItems(7) = !upc
            x.SubItems(8) = !Vat
            x.EnsureVisible
            x.Selected = True
```

Saving part

```
Public Sub SaveSales()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
 Do Until i = (ListView.ListItems.Count + 1)
 With ListView.ListItems(i)
       Connect.AddSales txtinvoice.Text, .Text, .SubItems(4), .SubItems(6), txtdate.Text, txtSubTotal.Text, _
                     txtDiscount.Text, txtTotal.Text, frmPayment.txtCash.Text, _
                     CDbl(frmPayment.txtCash.Text) - CDbl(txtTotal.Text), "Open", frmLogin.Cashier
 End With
i = i + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What/Where the error is?

Comment: No errors, am trying to include the VAT that i have added on the listview to save on the table. i dont know how to go about it am new to vb...  thanks

Comment: When i try to add .SubItems(8) i get error no datamember. someone please help

Comment: What is `Connect.AddSales` ? Has it been adjusted to receive additional parameter `.SubItem(8)`?

Comment: @George Yes thats right

Comment: Finally it is working, from the data environment adjust the SQLparameters to include 'Vat' which is '.subitems(8)'.    thanks George

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is working, from the data environment adjust the SQLparameters to include 'Vat' which is '.subitems(8)'. thanks George